# How to keep running iOS application (iOS 9+) in background till user changes wifi settings of iOS device

Tags: ios, background-process

In my application, the user needs to connect the device wifi to another wifi via the iOS settings. I want my app to remain in the background for some time(like 5 min max) without getting suspended, until the user connects to the other network and returns to the application.

I observe that my application gets removed from background during switching the device wifi. The application doesn't remain active in the background.

How do I keep the iOS application (iOS 9+) in background for some time i.e 5 min?

Comment: Why will your app be removed from the background? Is your app opening any socket connections? Or is it executing any bakcground tasks? If not, then as far as I know, your app won't get killed that easily unless the system is short on memory. I am not that sure, so correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Apps moving to the background are expected to put themselves into a
>   quiescent state as quickly as possible so that they can be suspended
>   by the system. If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a
>   little extra time to complete that task, it can call the
>   `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:` or
>   `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method of the `UIApplication`
>   object to request some additional execution time. Calling either of
>   these methods delays the suspension of your app temporarily, giving it
>   a little extra time to finish its work. Upon completion of that work,
>   your app must call the `endBackgroundTask:` method to let the system
>   know that it is finished and can be suspended.

(source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read [iOS Backgrounding with Tasks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/) .

> The time App will be in background in 10 minutes that is 600 seconds.

You can know time remaining using the code

```
NSLog(@"Time Remaining: %f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
```

Since your need is just turning wifi on- It may take less than 10 minutes i think.

Hope my answer is Clear and Helpful.